# dynamic cast from array in c++

Tags: c++, vector, casting

I have a class `STSequencer` which extends `ofxDTanbileBase`.
I have a method which returns a `vector<ofxDTanbileBase>` based on the className i give.
I want to cast back to `STSequencer` but i get the following errors:

**'ofxDTangibleBase *' is not a class**

**Dynamic_cast from rvalue to reference type 'STSequencer &'**

This is how i try atm:

```
 vector<ofxDTangibleBase> sequencers = gTangibleList->findTangibleByClassName("STSequencer");

for (int i = 0; i < sequencers.size(); i++) {
    STSequencer &sequencer = dynamic_cast<STSequencer&>(&sequencers[i]);

}
```

This is the method:

```
vector<ofxDTangibleBase> ofxDGlobalTangibleList::findTangibleByClassName(const char *className) {

    vector<ofxDTangibleBase> returnVector;

    for (int i = 0; i < _tangibles.size(); i++) {
        ofxDTangibleBase &t = _tangibles[i];
        if (t.className == className) {
            returnVector.push_back(t);
        }
    }

    return returnVector;
}
```

A better way is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`STSequencer &sequencer = dynamic_cast<STSequencer&>`

should be

`STSequencer *sequencer = dynamic_cast<STSequencer*>`

or else remove the `&` in front of `sequencers[i]`.  By taking the address of `sequencers[i]`, you have a pointer.  But you are then trying to dynamic_cast to a reference, and that's not meaningful.

There are other risks if your design.  You might end up copying (and slicing) elements when you don't expect it.  I'm not sure what you're doing.  For this answer, I just looked at the line that failed to compile.

Comment: "You might end up copying (and slicing) elements when you don't expect it." can you explain why? I started c++ a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector does not actually contain `STSequencer` objects, so that cast will lead to undefined behavior, even after you fix the levels of indirection (reference vs pointer) problem.

If you really need polymorphism, you'll need to store addresses in the vector, not objects, because the vector makes assumptions about the size of its elements.

Try `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ofxDTanbileBase>>`.